# TTStyledText not displays string which has '<' charcter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

I am using TTStyledText to display text on my tableView. I came across a problem where, If my TTStyledText text contains '<' character than my complete text becomes null.

```
TTStyledText *text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:@"3<5" lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];

[tnc setText:text];

NSLog(@"tnc - %@ & Text is - %@", tnc, tnc.text);
```

tnc is of type `TTStyledTextLabel`.

Logs displays the object but text as `(null)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@"3&#x3C;5"` instead of `@"3<5"`

Here `<` is a special entity so you should use html code for `<` which is `&#x3C;` or `&lt;`     or `&#60;` [**defined here.**](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html)